# Add image to header using python-docx and docxtpl

Tags: python-docx

I have working code to insert an image into a DOCX template (using Jinja template format provided by docxtpl) but while the image works when inserted into the document body the image fails to render in the header. The insertion point in the document `{{p my_image}}` displays the message 'Read Error'.

I assume this is a bug/limitation in the python-docx library but I was wondering if there's a known workaround. I've tried 2 methods to create the image but both fail with the same 'Read Error' message only when used in the header:

Method 1:

```
sub_doc = self.template.new_subdoc()
p = sub_doc.add_paragraph()
r = p.add_run()
r.add_picture(output_path)
return sub_doc
```

Method 2:

```
from docxtpl import InlineImage
return InlineImage(template, image_path, width, height)
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Old question but maybe someone need it.

I write images into the header of a DOCX file with the following by using the docx module. In my case I have to write the image into a table.

```
from docx import Document
from docx.shared import Inches

header = doc.sections[0].header

#Insert table with 2 rows and 3 columns
headertable = header.add_table(2, 3, Inches(6))
headertable.style("borderColor:black")
a = headertable.cell(0, 0)
b = headertable.cell(1, 0)
A = a.merge(b)

#add table in header
headertab_cells = headertable.rows[0].cells

ht0 = headertab_cells[0].add_paragraph()
kh = ht0.add_run()
kh.add_picture('logo.jpg', width=Inches(1))
```

Comment: Why Microsoft? WHY? :(

Comment: Yes sometimes your company want to use Microsoft Products and you have to use it 